# Error using sound_play

Tags: ros, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What I want to do: I want to say any text :)
I try to use sound_play and say.py. I try to launch soundplay_node using

```
roslaunch sound_play soundplay_node.launch
```

And I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/audio_common/sound_play/scripts/soundplay_node.py", line     43, in <module>
   from sound_play.msg import SoundRequest
ImportError: No module named sound_play.msg
```

What I shall do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92276/error-using-sound_play/) by [pelment](https://answers.ros.org/users/5425/pelment/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2013-10-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sergiiio](https://answers.ros.org/users/78323/sergiiio/) on 2021-07-26**:
I am new at this. How can i compile sound play node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did u compile the sound play node to generate the respective messages?

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2013-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pelment](https://answers.ros.org/users/5425/pelment/) on 2013-10-18**:
Hm, I did it once and forgot about the fact that I have a error with root access. Thank you, I built it again and now it works!